# No JUnit tests found in Eclipse using Groovy + Cucumber

Tags: eclipse, groovy, junit, cucumber

I have a Cucumber test in Groovy as follows

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import cucumber.junit.Cucumber
import cucumber.junit.Cucumber.Options

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@Options(features = ["classpath:CarDrive.feature"])
public class FuelCarTest {

}

import cucumber.annotation.en.Given
import cucumber.annotation.en.Then
import cucumber.annotation.en.When

public class FuelCarSteps {

    public FuelCarSteps() {
        println "FuelCarSteps::FuelCarSteps"
    }

    @Given("I have a car")
    def givenCar() {
        println "I have a car"
    }

    @When("^you fill it with 50 litres of fuel")
    def addFuel() {
        println "add fuel"
    }

    @Then("^the tank contains 60 litres")
    def checkBalance() {
        println "TODO: add check here"
    }
}
```

I can run the test fine using mvn test, but when I try to run it in Eclipse I get

```
No JUnit tests found
```

Tried cleaning, rebuilding & restarting

Answer (score 0):

Hi you need to create run configuration for the each test in junit

Provide full path ( like `package1.subpackege1.testclassname` ) in class input in run config

Answer (score 0):

Control, if you have any errors in the Groovy code, such as `Type of expression is statically unknown:` or similar. They don't show off as usual errors and could be almost invisible.